# How can a function takes another function WITH arguments, as a parameter?

Tags: python, functional-programming

```
def Wrapper(func):
  def MyPrint(message):
    print('Hello ' + message)
  
  func(MyPrint)

Wrapper(lambda my_print: my_print('world'))
```

I'm confused of the above code. I get that a function can take another function as parameter and use `func()` to invoke it, but how can `Wrapper(lambda my_print: my_print('world'))` call the inner function `MyPrint`? The `func` is a parameter, and the `lambda my_print: my_print('world')` is its argument, but somehow the argument seems to utilizes (penatrate through) an inner function inside `Wrapper`.

This is a very common pattern in JavaScript but confuses me. I think an explaination of what happened in detail might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(lambda my_print: my_print('world')` doesn't call `MyPrint` directly; `MyPrint` is passed as its argument in `func(MyPrint)`.

Try the substitution method:

```
Wrapper(lambda my_print: my_print('world'))
```

--->
`func` is bound to `lambda my_print: my_print('world')` in the body of `Wrapper`:

```
def MyPrint(message):
    print('Hello ' + message)
  
  (lambda my_print: my_print('world'))(MyPrint)
```

--->

`my_print` is bound to `MyPrint` in the body of the lambda:

```
def MyPrint(message):
    print('Hello ' + message)
  
  MyPrint('world')
```

---

Addendum: the same, but with a non-local function and no lambda, in case that makes it clearer:

```
def GreetingPrinter(message):
    print('Hello ' + message)

def Wrapper(func):
  func(GreetingPrinter)

def PrintWithWorld(printer):
    printer('World')

Wrapper(PrintWithWorld)
```

Comment: Nice! I think I get it now. `MyPrint` is passed to the lambda as an argument. 

This feels counter-intuitive, since the most of times, we pass arguments when calling the function `foo(my_arg)`, and here we provide a lambda and expect the real function to be passed in.

Comment: There's no difference between functions that take an empty argument list and those that take a non-empty argument list, or between a lambda function and other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer:
You are renaming in the local scope of 'Wrapper' function.
Detailed answer:
When 'Wrapper' gets called, it takes the throw away function `lambda my_print: my_print('World')` (now becomes 'func' in 'Wrapper' local scope). The throw away function needs the variable 'my_print' to be a function or it'll throw an error. That function must also take a variable itself, a preset string ('World'). 'MyPrint' predefined in the local scope of 'Wrapper' function, gets renamed as 'my_print', which takes the preset argument 'World' string. When 'func' is called (in local scope of 'Wrapper'), it return 'World' string as the argument for 'my_print' (which is 'MyPrint' just renamed) function. This prints 'Hello World' to the screen before the 'Wrapper' function closes out. When it closes, you are back in the global scope.